# How to solve the problem of installing Node.js in AWS Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Prerequisites**

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install git
git clone https://github.com/userName/projectName
```

**Description**

I just create an EC2 instance and connect to AWS Linux.
By following the instructions in this page
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

***After steps below***

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install --lts
```

**Problems**

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-12-23-12]$ nvm install --lts
Installing latest LTS version.
v18.12.1 is already installed.
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v18.12.1` to unset it.
```

How can I fix the problems?

**What I've tried**

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-12-23-12]$ nvm use --delete-prefix v18.12.1
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
[ec2-user@ip-123-12-23-12]$ node -v
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
[ec2-user@ip-123-12-23-12]$ nvm install --lts
Installing latest LTS version.
v18.12.1 is already installed.
```

Comment: Amazon linux 2 is too old, and does not support glib vs. 2.27 or 2.28. Try with latest ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, I solved with the command

```bash
nvm install 16
```